# toggle between two svg icons

Tags: html, svg

How can I put another `svg xmlnx` link here so that when the first svg has been clicked, it will toggle to another svg link?

My html:

```
<div class="input-box" *ngIf="loginForm.controls.password.untouched || loginForm.controls.password.valid">
    <input placeholder="***********" name="password" id="password" [type]="show ? 'text' : 'password'" formControlName="password" autocomplete="on">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" (click)="password()">
        <path d="M10 12a2 2 0 100-4 2 2 0 000 4z" />
        <path fill-rule="evenodd"d="M.458 10C1.732 5.943 5.522 3 10 3s8.268 2.943 9.542 7c-1.274 4.057-5.064 7-9.542 7S1.732 14.057.458 10zM14 10a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"clip-rule="evenodd" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not make sense at all. Would you like to change the namespace (the xmlns attribute)? It is a namespace not a link/resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript to change the attribute.

```
        <input placeholder="***********" name="password" id="password" [type]="show ? 'text' : 'password'" formControlName="password" autocomplete="on">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onclick="changesvg()" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" (click)="password()" id="Svg">
            <path d="M10 12a2 2 0 100-4 2 2 0 000 4z" />
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"d="M.458 10C1.732 5.943 5.522 3 10 3s8.268 2.943 9.542 7c-1.274 4.057-5.064 7-9.542 7S1.732 14.057.458 10zM14 10a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"clip-rule="evenodd" />
        </svg>
    </div>
    <script>
        var Source = true
        var Svg=document.getElementById("Svg")
        function changesvg(){
            Source= !Source
            console.log(Source)
            if (Source==true){
                Svg.setAttribute("xmlns","http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
            }
            else{
                Svg.setAttribute("xmlns","New link")
            }
        }
    </script>
```